# C string parser inside another parser

Tags: c, string, parsing

I have the following string :

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.0;;User-Agent: Wget/1.11.4;;Accept: */*;;Host: www.google.com;;Connection
```

I use the following code to parse each element:

```
    while (parser != NULL){
        printf ("%s\n",parser);         
        parser = strtok (NULL, ";;");
    }
```

This outputs:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.11.4
Accept: */*
Host: www.google.com
Connection
```

Now I only need to get host web address which in this case is www.google.com. So first I want to separate it from other stuff.

To do that I put another parser inside my previous one like so:

```
    while (parser != NULL){
        char * pars = strtok (string,":");
        while (pars != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", pars);
            pars = strtok (NULL, ":");
        }
        parser = strtok (NULL, ";;");
    }
```

The output of this is some messed up stuff. I do not understand why... Can anyone see mistake? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is that `strtok` is non-reentrant. Because the function uses static variables to save the state (this is what lets you call `strtok` with `NULL` as the first parameter) you cannot set up calls of `strtok` in nested loops: once you tell `strtok` to parse with `":"` delimiter, it "forgets" the state of parsing with the `";"` delimiter.

Switching to re-entrant version of `strtok` - [`strtok_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r), will fix this problem. This function requires you to supply an extra parameter, `savePtr`. Important: you need to supply two different variables for your `savePtr` for `strtok_r` in the inner and the outer loops, otherwise the code would exhibit the same behavior.

Note: `strtok_r` is not part of C standard. However, most popular C libraries make it available. In case your library does not have `strtok_r`, locate source code for it, and add it to your own code base.

Comment: I knew `strtok` had this problem; I was not aware of a re-entrant version. Cool.

Comment: Note that `strtok_r` is not C-standard (but POSIX).

Comment: @Kninnug That's true. I added a note to mention that. Thank you!

Comment: can you may be give an example, or change my code so it behaves correctly, please?

Comment: What about the fact that `strtok(NULL, ";;")` stops at the first instance of `;` and not the first instance of `;;`? It sort-of works here since there are no individual `;`, but won't you have a `;` at the start of the next string found?

Answer (score 0):

There is a big problem with your approach - apart from the issue of `strtok` not being re-entrant. That is that `strtok` looks for a "match with any token" - so `strtok(NULL, ";;")` will stop at the first `;`, not at the first `;;`.

I would go about this a different way - you are looking for a specific string (`"\nHost: "`) - search for that, then find the bit that follows. This seems like a more robust solution.

Also note that `strtok` modifies its argument - basically it will add `'\0'` where it finds the token, so you will not be able to re-use the string after it was manipulated by `strtok`. If you want to use the string afterwards, you need to make a copy first.

All of which suggests that you want to re-think your parsing strategy.  How about

char *inputString = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.0;;User-Agent: Wget/1.11.4;;Accept: */*;;Host: www.google.com;;Connection";
   char *temp, *hostString, *endHost;
   temp = strstr(inputString, ";;Host:") + 7; // point right after "Host:"
   endHost = strstr(temp, ";;");
   nChar = (int)(endHost - temp) + 1;
   hostString = malloc(nChar);
   strcpy(hostString, temp, nChar);

This is just to find / extract the host string.